Ticket to Ride scoring
I have a destination card for LA-Las Vegas.
I claim that route early in the game, so I get the points.
At the end of the game, I still have the card.
Do I get the points again?

You do not reveal, or claim points for, the Destination Tickets you have until the end of the game. During the game, you score points for the routes you claim based on their length - 1 point for a 1-train route up to 15 points for a 6-train route. Then, at the end of the game, players reveal all of their Destination Tickets to gain points for completed ones and lose points for incomplete ones.
